# Diagonal matrix in opposite direction in C

Tags: c, matrix

I have a C code to produce diagonal identity matrix. The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
void main()
{
    int n,m,a,b,c,d,i,j;
    int ar1[100][100];
      
    printf("Enter value of n to create a square matrix of order n (odd no.): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf(" matrix in diagonal direction is - \n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
            if (ar1[j]==ar1[i]) {
                ar1[j][i] = 2;
                printf("%d, ", ar1[j][i]);
            } else {
                ar1[j][i] = -1;
                printf("%d, ", ar1[j][i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

which gives me a result like this:

```
 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1,  2, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1,  2, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1,  2, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1,  2
```

but I want to print diagonal matrix in opposite direction like this:

```
-1, -1, -1, -1,  2, 
-1, -1, -1,  2, -1, 
-1, -1,  2, -1, -1, 
-1,  2, -1, -1, -1, 
 2, -1, -1, -1, -1
```

Can somebody help me out, as to how to print diagonal matrix in opposite direction? I want to change the actual matrix not only the output

---

I have updated my code like this (shown below) but still I am getting error (shown below)

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
void main()
{
     int n,m,a,b,c,d,i,j,s;
         int ar1[100][100];
      
     printf("Enter value of n to create a square matrix of order n (odd no.): ");
     scanf("%d",&n);

         printf("Enter m: (odd no.) ");
     scanf("%d",&m );
      
     
         if(n>m)
          { 
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
           for(j=0;j<n;j++)
           {
              
                       for(a=1;a<=(m-1)/2;a++){
                       if(ar1[i-a]==ar1[j]){
                       ar1[i][j] = 2;
                       printf("%d, ",ar1[i][j]);
                      }
                      }

                      for(a=(m+1)/2;a<=(n-1);a++){
                       if(ar1[i-a]==ar1[j]){
                       ar1[i][j] = -1;
                       printf("%d, ",ar1[i][j]);
                      }
                      }

                      if(ar1[i]==ar1[j]){
                       ar1[i][j] = 2;
                       printf("%d, ",ar1[i][j]);
                      }

                     for(a=1;a<=(m-1)/2;a++){
                       if(ar1[i+a]==ar1[j]){
                       ar1[i][j] = 2;
                       printf("%d, ",ar1[i][j]);

                      }
                      }

        for(a=(m+1)/2;a<=(n-1);a++){
                       if(ar1[i+a]==ar1[j]){
                       ar1[i][j] = -1;
                       printf("%d, ",ar1[i][j]);
                      }
                      }
s = flip (ar1[100][100], n);

             }
           printf("\n");
     }

void flip(int a[100][100], int n) {
 int t;
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
     for (j=0; j<n/2; j++) {
         t=a[i][j];
         a[i][j] = a[i][n-1-j];
         a[i][n-1-j] = t;
       }
   }
  }
    }
             
}
```

and am getting errors like this

```
      /tmp/cc72v9hd.o: In function `main':
     faltu2.c:(.text+0x629): undefined reference to `flip'
     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: If You don't want to modify already written code, take the result.Write a function that can reverse elements in the array and apply it to every row in the result matrix.

Comment: But before doing anything further, first **format your code.**

Comment: do you even know what is the line "ar1[j]==ar1[i]" doing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just change output, but not actual matrix, simply replace this outer loop:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    ...
```

with this one:

```
for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
    ...
```

---

**UPDATE**. If you need to flip the matrix, simply use function or code like this:

```
 void flip(int a[][], int n) {
     int i,j,t;
     for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
         for (j=0; j<n/2; i++) {
             t=a[i][j];
             a[i][j] = a[i][n-1-j];
             a[i][n-1-j] = t;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I want to change the actual matrix not only the output

Comment: added function to flip the matrix

Comment: I am getting error unndefined reference to flip. I have called flip as flip(ar1[100][100], n); Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

Just reversing any loop, ie, iterating from `n-1` should do.. Below is my version,

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n,m,a,b,c,d,i,j;
    int ar1[100][100];

    printf("Enter value of n to create a square matrix of order n (odd no.): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf(" matrix in diagonal direction is - \n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                    //if(ar1[j]==ar1[i]){       // any two garbage values can be equal
                    if(j==i)
                    {
                            ar1[j][i] = 2;
                            printf("%d, ",ar1[j][i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            ar1[j][i] = -1;
                            printf("%d, ",ar1[j][i]);
                    }

            }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to change the actual matrix not only the output